# How do I split rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to split the rows while maintaing the values.

How can I split the rows like that?

The data frame below is an example.

[image]

the output that i want to see

[image]

Comment: `df.set_index('Value').stack().reset_index(name = 'IDs').drop('level_1', 1)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pd.melt( ). Read the documentation for more information: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

I tried working on your problem.

`import pandas as pd`

`melted_df = data.melt(id_vars=['value'], var_name="ToBeDropped", value_name="ID1")`

This would show a warning because of the unambiguity in the string passed for "value_name" argument. This would also create a new column which I have assigned the name already. The new column will be called 'ToBeDropped'. Below code will remove the column for you.

`df = melted_df.drop(columns = ['ToBeDropped'])`

'df' will be your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

via `wide_to_long`:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='ID', i='value',
                     j='ID_number').reset_index(0)
```

via `set_index` and `stack`:

```
df = df.set_index('value').stack().reset_index(name='IDs').drop('level_1', 1)
```

via `melt`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='value', value_name="ID1").drop('variable', 1)
```

Comment: it works. thanks. if I have 30columns, for example, columns is trans_1, num_1, name_1, in_id1, out_id1, in_name1, out_name1 ... trans_4, num_4, name_4, in_id4, out_id4, in_name4, out_name4 and value. 
If I want to separate each column based on 'value', what I have to do?  The code you told me can only be separated by one column.

Comment: @mineral It can be done via `wide_to_long` just add the values in `stubnames` like - `subnames = ['ID', 'name' , 'trans']`. etc.